# Change target folder in PloneFormGen Custom ScriptAdapter to other folder in site

Tags: plone, ploneformgen

From custom script Adapter template:

```
# Find our target folder from the context. The ID of
# our target folder is "submissions"
target = context.submissions
```

What is the syntax to create the object in a submissions folder at the top of the site?

ie. `http://mysite/submissions/`

Answer (score 2):

Get the portal root:

```
portal_root = context.portal_url.getPortalObject()
target = portal_root.submissions
```